# How to use a variable in a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an Object called `selectedTeam` in the jQuery function I can *log* the `selectedTeam`'s "first name", but in an another `.js` file that belongs to an another `.html` file, if I try to *log* the `selectedTeam["Selected_Driver Weight"]`, I get undefined instead of the real value.

obj.js:

```
var selectedTeam = {
"Selected_Driver Weight": "none",
"Selected_Car Weight": "none",
"Selected_Car Speed": "none",
"Selected_Car Break Disk": "none"
```

}

main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#select-team_mercedes").click(function(){
         isMercedesSelected = true;
         console.log("You have successfully selected "+ Mercedes["Team Name"]);
            //Set for selected
            selectedTeam["Selected_Driver Weight"] = Mercedes["Team Name"];
            console.log(selectedTeam["Selected_Driver Weight"]);
        });
});
```

2nd html's .js file:

```
console.log(selectedTeam["Selected_Driver Weight"]);
```

I'm getting: `undefined`;

Comment: Have you added a reference to this JS file in the 2ns HTML?

Comment: you should define obj.js first, so that it can be available for later scripts define

Comment: I tested your code in the Developer Tools, it's working. //Gets *none*. You can check those in the Developer Tools. 
Could you check your file path or define js files?

Comment: I tried everything but it gets undefined too. If I assign a variable as SelectedTeam's firstname: value, it doesn't work, but if I pass it as a string (for examlpe: "a"), it loaded and works, But I wanna use his value with an assigned variable to it.

Answer (score -1):

in obj.js do the following:
export const selectedTeam = ...

in main.js do the following:
import {selectedTeam} from 'path/to/your/obj.js'

Comment: If the problem was module experts, then there would be a ReferenceError because `selectedTeam` wouldn't be declared before reaching the point where it was determined that `selectedTeam["Selected_Driver Weight"]` is undefined.